# Selenium with Java send keys with keys.TAB

Tags: java, selenium, key, send

Hi I am working with selenium using Java. I have an editable table in which I need to enter nearly 12-17 values continuously. what I was trying is:

```
Prdcode.sendkeys(keys.TAB,"1000",keys.TAB,keys.TAB,"2000",....etc);
```

Now the problem is that it's not entering all the values; If I send 1000, it enters only 10 and triggers tab.

I have even tried `"\t"` but the problem is that it will append all the values instead of 'clear and enter'. Can some one help me on this?

Comment: Why do you send `Keys.TAB`? Is it to jump from textField to textField in a form? Also do you mean it is only entering a portion of the value (e.g. `"10"` instead of `"1000"`), or only 10 values from the (12) passed values? And finally, what is `Prdcode`? A `WebElement`? Or something else? Please post a bit more code so we know what is going on.

Comment: Ya.procode is a web element(cell).iam triggering tab to jump from one cell to next cell in table.if you see my code..iam triggering TAB to jump to next cell and enter 1000 in that.but it's entering 10(10 instead of 1000) and triggering TAB.......

Comment: sendKeys will only work on the Prdcode webelement. For jumping to another cell to enter data you got to give selenium that webelement before you use sendkeys.

Comment: Try giving 'waits' in between

Comment: But how to customize send keys to have 'wait' in between

Answer (score 1):

> First of all it is not `sendkeys()`. Please use `sendKeys()`.

**Solution:**

Use multiple `sendkeys()` as given below.

```
Prdcode.sendKeys(keys.TAB);
Prdcode.sendKeys("1000");
Prdcode.sendKeys(keys.TAB);
Prdcode.sendKeys("2000");
Prdcode.sendKeys(.......);
```

**Possible problems and solution :**

1. `Prdcode` is only one element and script is overwriting existing data. Here you can **change next element as per given HTML**. [Refer this](http://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html). **Example :**

   ```
   ele1.sendKeys("1000");
   ele2.sendKeys("2000");
   ele3.sendKeys(.......);
   ```

   **Note : No need to use `Prdcode.sendKeys(keys.TAB);`**
2. `Prdcode` have some **data entry limit.** (Please check manually). If yes then **script can not add string more than limit (Valid scenario).**
3. If **scenario 1** is entering data randomly, then use `Thread.sleep(1000);` between `sendKeys()`.

**See :**

```
ele1.sendKeys("1000");
Thread.sleep(1000);
ele2.sendKeys("2000");
Thread.sleep(1000);
ele3.sendKeys(.......);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```